# Test protected methods inside a method with PHPUnit 3.7

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd

I need test the makeFileMatch function, and this funcion have 2 protected methods inside.
What is the correct behavior for do it?
I have a mock of this class, i need to create a reflaction of this methods, and change your return value?
I need a example :D

```
public function makeFileMatch($templateUrl,$width,$height)
{
    $result = $this->assembleCurlRequest($templateUrl, $width, $height);

    return $this->parseJsonResult($result);
}

/**
 * @param $result
 * @return array
 */
protected function transformJsonInArray($result)
{
    return (array)json_decode($result);
}

/**
 * @param $result
 * @return bool|string
 */
protected function tryToRetrieveUrlFromJsonResponse($result)
{
    if ($result['status'] == 'success') {

        return $this->getCreatedThumbByUrl($result['data']->url);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: If your question is: How to I call protected methods in a PHPUnit test, you should take a look at this awesome blogpost: https://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html  Basically you can use PHP Reflection to change the accessibility of a method.

Comment: i know do it, but i dont know is a way to change the return of those methods after i've changed your visibility